# UIWebview goBack method not working iOS 11 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I use a local HTML file displayed in a UIWebview to display "Help" in my iPad app. The web view is embedded in another view which also has back and forward buttons linked to the goBack and goForward methods.The buttons work as expected in the iOS 10.2 simulator, but not in in the iOS 11 simulators. In iOS 11 when I tap on a link in the HTML file the link works, but the back button does not, despite the fact that canGoBack is true. Oddly enough the back button starts to work after I tap on a link that returns me to the top of the page. Is this an Apple bug or is there a workaround? My method:

```
    -(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"HVC in goBack canGoBack is %d", self.webView.canGoBack);
[self.webView goBack];
}
```

Output when the go back button does not work:

2017-11-10 09:32:41.752614-0700 MHRS[2436:151546] HVC in goBack canGoBack is 1

Answer (score 0):

If your initial page in UIWebView is not remote page  after clicking any link in this first page you will be redirected, but goBack method will became unavailable try this method it may work for you.

```
- (void) goBackToRederect {
        if ([self.webView canGoBack]) {
                [self.webView goBack];
            } else {
                [self.webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:url];
        } }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work even when canGoBack is true so your suggestion won't work. Works fine in iOS 10.2 simulator. A bug in UIWebview for iOS 11?